# What is deep immutability?

Tags: javascript, promise, immutability

When reading the [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/) specification I came across the term 'deep immutability'. The text says:

> Here, “must not change” means immutable identity (i.e. ===), but does not imply deep immutability.

What is deep immutability?
Can someone explain with an example?

Comment: You have to think along the lines of how `===` works and what it does to establish whether two things are equal.

Comment: Or take a look at how `const` works. `const` values have immutable identity but are not deeply immutable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once a promise has been resolved any attempts to resolve it again will have no effect, which means that the resolved value will always have strict equality to the original resolved value. This doesn't mean, however, that the value can't change i.e. *"does not imply deep immutability"*.

This can be demonstrated with an example:

```
var value = [1];
var p = Promise.resolve(value);
p.then(a => console.log(a));                  // [1]
p.then(a => console.log(a === value));        // true

p.then(a => { a = [2]; console.log(a);});     // [2]
p.then(a => console.log(a));                  // [1]

p.then(a => { a[0] = 2; console.log(a);});    // [2]
p.then(a => console.log(a));                  // [2]
p.then(a => console.log(a === value));        // true
```

As you can see the value returned from the resolved promise remains the same Object value throughout - `a === value`. Attempts to bind the object to a different value only apply within the scope of the then block and we see the original Object value the next time we call the then method on the promise.

When we change the value of one of this array's properties, in this case the first element, we notice that this change affects the original value and therefore also the resolved value returned from this promise. If the resolved value had deep immutability then all of its properties and their properties would be immutable, however we've just shown that this isn't the case.

Comment: Great answer and very useful example! Can you explain this bit: "Once a promise has been resolved any attempts to resolve it again will have no effect"? This sounds to me like it might be unrelated to deep immutability, and is actually another part of the Promises/A+ spec. But maybe I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: This explains why you will always receive the original Object value from a promise, because it can't be resolved to another value, and also why they use the terminology "must not change". That wording can be misconstrued as meaning deep immutability, which is how it relates and why the spec clarifies that it's not.

Answer (score 2):

In Object Oriented Languages, there is no good way to lock the objects propertys.  For example, if you have multiple instantiations of an object in your app, and you change a property value on one of those references, then the data now differs between at least one of the references of that object.  Deeply Immutable ensures that the data for that object stays locked, programmatically, by spec, across all references.

If the application specs state deep immutability, then it would be illegal to either mutate the object, or reassign its fields.

If the application states shallow immutability, you still cant reassign the objects fields, hence immutable, but you are allowed to mutate the objects references.

There is a great article on this here https://homes.cs.washington.edu/~mernst/pubs/immutability-aliasing-2013-lncs7850.pdf

According to the article, most clients prefer deep immatibility.